# Regular expression for working hours (e.g. 8a12p)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a schedule application (JS) that needs to both validate an input, and get the various parts of the input. Some sample valid inputs:

- `8a12p`(8am to 12pm)
- `6a6p` (6am to 6pm)

My regex string is currently `^[1-9]|1[0-2][a|p][1-9]|1[0-2][a|p]$`, but it doesn't seem to work for all cases (e.g. `8a12x` still is valid), and the parts don't seem to split properly in JS. (I need to be able to get the various parts (e.g. `[ "8", "a", "12", "p" ]` for valid regex.)

Thanks!

Comment: `[a|p]` should be `[ap]`. Anything inside a character class is allowed once, unless a quantifier (`*` or `+`) or range (`{}`)is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the correct parenthesis.

This works: `^([1-9]|1[0-2])(a|p)([1-9]|1[0-2])(a|p)$`

Recomended site for building regex's https://regex101.com/

---

**Explanation on yours**

Your regex `^[1-9]|1[0-2][a|p][1-9]|1[0-2][a|p]$` looks for either

`^[1-9]` or `1[0-2][a|p][1-9]` or `[1|p]$` and since the first works with your example (since it starts with a number between 1 and 9 the whole regex is true.

Comment: May want to expand the numbers a bit: ^[0-9]|1[0-2][a|p][0-9]|1[0-2][a|p]$  in case somebody wants 02am  depends on the format you'll be expecting

Comment: @sniperd that regex wont work. besides the fact that it is missing the parenthesis too, `^([0-9]|1[0-2])(a|p)([0-9]|1[0-2])(a|p)$` will not work for 02a9p instead it will work for 0a0p which is weird. `^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[0-9])(a|p)([0-9]|1[0-2]|0[0-9])(a|p)$` is what would do that but seems like an overkill if it is not needed

Comment: whoops, I copy/pasted from the wrong one.  you got the idea though.  I've just seen a lot of date formatted stuff come in for midnight and as 00a.